# txfonts minus sign

Tags: math-fonts

I used XeLaTeX to compile the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[\sum a^k=p\sum a^{k−1}−q\sum a^{k−2}+r\sum a^{k−3}.\]
\end{document}
```

I found that the minus sign in the display doesn't show. So the superscript was like `k1`.

Why is there such a problem? Are there any methods for times math fonts that're more stable?

Comment: The minus sign shows for me in both places when I compile that sample code.

Comment: Are you sure that is not a pdf viewer zoom problem?

Comment: @frabjous I forgot to say, use XeLaTeX.

Comment: Don't do `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. And don't use `txfonts`, but `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the minus symbol in your code is an actual minus symbol `−` rather than a hyphen `-`. If I just replace the minus symbols with hyphens, they appear in the output as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[\sum a^k=p\sum a^{k-1}-q\sum a^{k-2}+r\sum a^{k-3}.\]
\end{document}
```

Also, if you want to use a Times clone you should probably be using [`newtx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) rather than `txfonts`.

Comment: You're right. But without ```txfonts```, LaTeX formulae supports both.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, is `\everymath{\displaystyle}` really needs?

Comment: @MadyYuvi it is certainly not needed, I just copied the code from the question and I did not remove it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason for using XeTeX with `txfonts`, because the fonts are only available in Type1 format. Besides, `txfonts` is to be considered obsolete because the fonts it provides have many problems with spacings and character sidebearings.

<sup>And don't do `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. Even if you think that it's good, trust me and don't use it.</sup>

With the fixed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[\sum a^k=p\sum a^{k−1}−q\sum a^{k−2}+r\sum a^{k−3}.\]

\end{document}
```

I get

```
Missing character: There is no − ("2212) in font ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1!
```

four times.

This happens when copying material from other sources. Doing “find and replace” would work, but it's probably easier if you make U+2212 known to TeX math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% Make U+2212 MINUS SIGN known
\Umathcodenum"2212=\Umathcodenum`\-

\begin{document}

\[\sum a^k=p\sum a^{k−1}−q\sum a^{k−2}+r\sum a^{k−3}.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `txfonts`

[image]

Look closely for the differences, in particular for the minus sign. There are many others.

Comment: So if I don't write `\everymath{\displaystyle}` and add `\displaystyle` to all inline formulae (which I did before), would it be better?

Comment: @youthdoo No, you shouldn't use `\displaystyle` to inline formulas to begin with.